# How to declare a generic type Multi-Dimensional array in java

Tags: java

I want to store an array of 100 int elements in rows ie 1 row of 100 int datatypes.And every single element contains an array of 100 objects.How to do this in java or android.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and self-contradictory.  On the one hand, you say that the elements have type `int`.  On the other hand, you say that each element contains an array of 100 objects.  It is impossible for an `int` to contain anything.  Please try to express yourself more clearly.

Comment: Sorry ,Actually I want to store 100 Objects in every column in 200x100 matrix

Answer (score 6):

Use a collection, a "List of List":

```
List<List<YourType>> matrix2D = new ArrayList<List<YourType>>();
```

This structure can easily store a table with 200 rows and 100 columns where each element is of type `YourType`.

Otherwise - if your size is fixed and you just want to store `YourType` values, theres no need for generics:

```
int rows = 200;
int columns = 200;
YourType[][] matrix2D = new YourType[rows][columns];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can initialize and fill a two-dimensional Object array:

```
    Object value = 42;
    int rows = 100;
    int columns = 100;
    Object[][] myData = new Object[rows][columns];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            myData[r][c] = value;
        }
    }
```

Note that the primitive int value 42 is autoboxed when it is stored in the Object[][]. If you don't want this you could use an int[][] instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your type is int, it which be *much* more compact than using Integer type. (up to 6x smaller)
To create a fixed size array you can

```
int[][] matrix = new int[200][100];
// set all values to 42.
for(int[] row : matrix) Arrays.fill(row, 42);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this.

100 T(Your Object) Objects in 200x100 matrix(array)

```
T[][][] t = new T[200][100][100] ; 

t[0][0][1] = new T();
t[0][0][2] = new T();
...
t[0][0][99] = new T();
```